# FORM No envia por POST algunos campos que provienen de MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, post, form-submit

Estoy haciendo un formulario de la siguiente manera:

```
    <form id="datosventa" name="datosventa" method="POST" action="nventalentes2.php">
        <?php
        $montura = $_POST['categoryName'];
        $paciente = $_POST['paciente'];

          $query2 = $con -> query ("SELECT * FROM monturas WHERE id = $montura");

          while ($valores2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
            ?>
                <input disabled type="text" name="id_montura" id="id_montura" value="<?php echo $valores2['id'] ?>" style="width: 50px;">
                <input disabled type="text" name="nombre_montura" id="nombre_montura" value="<?php echo $valores2['nombre'] ?>" style="width: 250px;">
                <input disabled type="text" name="precio_montura" id="precio_montura" value="<?php echo $valores2['precio'] ?>" style="width: 80px;"><br>
            <?php
          }

          $query3 = $con -> query ("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = $paciente");

          while ($valores3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
            ?>
                <input disabled type="text" name="id_cliente" id="id_cliente" value="<?php echo $valores3['id_cliente'] ?>" style="width: 50px;">
                <input disabled type="text" name="nombre_cliente" id="nombre_cliente" value="<?php echo $valores3['nombre'],$valores3['apellidos'] ?>" style="width: 250px;">
            <?php
          }
         ?>
```

El caso, es que el resto de campos de más abajo son inputs o selects normales...

Estos campos

Al realizar el submit, no los envía, como si no pertenecieran al FORM, el caso que al hacer submit, muestra una vista previa de todo lo rellenado anteriormente.

Creo que me he explicado bien, si alguien pudiera ayudarme o tiene todavía alguna duda, me puede preguntar.

Muchísimas gracias de ante mano a la comunidad.

Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes cambiar el disable por readonly="readonly", ya que los disabled no se enviaran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes eliminar el atributo "disabled" de los elementos input para que puedan ser enviados.

Espero sea de utilidad.

Agrego un enlace donde explica el funcionamiento del atributo "disabled".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled

Comment: En fín, desconocia eso, si que funciona! Ni te imaginas las vueltas y las veces que he reprogramado todo de varias formas.

Comment: muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: Si no te preocupes. Un favor, puedes marcar mi respuesta como la correcta. Gracias.

Comment: Diego sugiero que mejores la respuesta, indicando la documentación donde se indica que los elementos marcados como `disabled` no se reciben al enviar el formulario. Espero ese dato para otorgarte +1. Gracias.

Comment: Listo Cedano, se agregó el enlace de la documentación. Gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Hola! He marcado la respuesta como "v" el problema que no entiendo el por que no me deja darle +1 :/

Comment: Gracias Javier. Al parecer debes tener 15 puntos de reputación para poder votar como positivo. Más info aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

puesto que aparentemente no tengo la suficiente reputación como para poder comentar en las respuestas de otras personas lo haré de este modo...

Por el uso que le estás dando al atributo `disabled`, intuiré que el atributo que estabas buscando en realidad es `readonly`, el cual, a diferencia de disabled, sí que te permite enviar los datos con el formulario.

Saludos